# AutoCompleteBox binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, autocomplete

I get a strange behaviour when manipulating the ItemsSource property of the AutoCompleteBox:
Whenever the ItemsSource changed from an Empty collection to a non-Empty collection (i.e. I'm trying to populating the Drop down list) , the drop down doesn't get populated.

When the collection is in non-empty state, and then changing the collection, the drop down appears and populate as it should.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This caused by the behaviour of the AutoCompleteBox control: it only shows its Items in reaction of keyboard pressed. So, if there're no items to display RIGHT after the key was pressed, no items will be displayed (make sense...). The population of those items happens when a call to a Web service returns, so there's a delay between the actual key press, and the change of the ItemsSource of the AutoCompleteBox.